# Can I vent basement bathroom plumbing through an existing 2" vent?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, basement

Can I tie a basement bathroom with 3 fixtures into a 2" existing vent? The vent currently supplies basement sink and washing machine with the upstairs sink and dishwasher.  The upstairs also uses this as a drain I believe.  Would this be considered a wet vent?

Comment: If things above use it as a drain, it's a wet vent, and that seriously impacts how much you can attach to it.

Comment: Thank you.  May look at a different route.